# A complicated python except

Tags: python

```
stmt = "Iomrscr yn wore"
mix  = "C'r eotrA,snep!"
for i in range(0, len(stmt), 2):
    stmt = stmt[:i] + mix[i] + stmt[i + 1:]

    print stmt
```

I know the answer for this question. However, I just do not know how this works. Can someone helps explain how you read this code? thx

Comment: You "know the answer" for what question? There's no question. Also, the code you posted doesn't seem to do anything but print a few lines of gibberish.

Comment: Have you tried breaking it down further?

Each time through the loop, what is `i`? What is `stmt[:i]`? What is `mix[i]`? What is `stmt[i + 1:]`? What part exactly don't you understand?

Comment: @kindall: Actually, the last line it prints is *not* gibberish, which is presumably the point.

Comment: @hkus10 Personally, I don't know the question of your answer.

Comment: Not complicated at all.  See the explanation below.

Comment: @hkus10: is this kind of homework? If so, please tag then your question appropriately manner! Thanks

Comment: The last line of the output is a single exclamation point, which I don't think is particularly enlightening.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

Let me break down the lines for you:

```
stmt = "Iomrscr yn wore"
mix  = "C'r eotrA,snep!"
```

These two lines simply defined 2 strings.

`for i in range(0, len(stmt), 2):`

This `for` statement says loop over every value of `i` in the array created by `range(0, len(stmt), 2)`  Importantly, the final 2 in the call to `range()` says to only take every other number, that is 0, 2, 4, 6 ... up to `len(stmt)`.

```
stmt = stmt[:i] + mix[i] + stmt[i + 1:]
```

This line says take everything in `stmt` up to index `i`, add the item at index `i` from `mix` then take everything from after index `i + 1` to the end.  The use of square brackets indicates a segment, you use it in the form `someArray[from:to]`.  It also works for strings as in this case and I believe it should work for tuples and dictionaries too.  If you don't provide a `from` then it starts at the 0 index and if you don't provide a `to` it goes to the end.  Note, the to is **not** inclusive.

Importantly, remember your range is every other index; 0,2,4,6...  Therefore, the first time you loop through, replacing `i` for it's actual value you have:

```
stmt = stmt[:0] + mix[0] + stmt[0 + 1:]
```

The second time you will have:

```
stmt = stmt[:2] + mix[2] + stmt[2 + 1:]
```

If you actually replace `stmt` and `mix` with the substrings being sliced out we see for this second loop (note I've already done the replacement for the first loop):

```
stmt = "Co" + "r" + "rscr yn wore"
```

Can you see that you will end up replacing every other letter in stmt with every other letter in mix?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easier to explain from the inside out;

```
    stmt = stmt[:i] + mix[i] + stmt[i + 1:]
```

- stmt[:i] is the start of the string, up to but not including offset i (so the head of the string *does not change*)
- mix[i] is a character from offset i in the other string
- stmt[i+1:] is the rest of the string, from the offset after i to the end (so the tail of the string *does not change*)

so in total this says "make a new string, same as the old string, but substitute the corresponding character from mix at offset i".

So what offsets do we do this to?

It is called in a loop,

```
for i in range(0, len(stmt), 2):
```

range(a,b,c) generates a sequence of numbers: a, a+c, a+2c, a+3c... a+Nc < b

Python strings are indexed starting at 0 - the first character is stmt[0] - and len(string) is the number of characters in the string, so the last character is at stmt[len(stmt)-1]. So this loop gives i the values (0,2,4,6...) up to but not including the first too-high index. In effect the loop says "swap the first character, and the third character, and the fifth character... for as many characters as possible without going off the end of the string".

A more direct way of writing this would be

```
stmt = "Iomrscr yn wore"
mix  = "C'r eotrA,snep!"

print ''.join(d[i%2] for i,d in enumerate(zip(mix,stmt)))
```

which says "pair up characters from mix and stmt, index them, and take a letter from mix when the index is even and from stmt when the index is odd; then join all the characters back into a string and print it".